# How to dive into philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, learning-methods

I'm a high school student with some basic knowledge of philosophy by far (I've taken an Intro to Philosophy course online, read Plato's *Republic*, some Camus, some Nietzsche and plenty of Marx), but given the many fields of philosophy I am not entirely sure how to attain a deeper understanding of each branch of philosophy in an organized fashion. Many people tell me to wait until college, but my personal inclinations prevent me from doing so.

Advice, please?

Thanks!

IFitNoNietzsche

Comment: PS if you do a search here you can find where people have made requests for references:  introduction to philosophy, history of philosophy,  reference requests.

Comment: Whatever philosopher or philosophical period you are interested in, try also to study the History of that period too. For instance, what was going on in Europe when German philosopher X was writing? Try to study the history of the period the philosopher was writing in. Almost everything you read now you will probably end up revising later, but no matter, continue to pursue your interests and read all the history you can (eg Ancient Greece, Europe Since 1500 etc , whatever applies).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to start philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/best-way-to-start-philosophy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some good introductions to philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4248/what-are-some-good-introductions-to-philosophy)

Answer (score 1):

Diving into philosophy can be overwhelming. A good place to start is by watching youtube videos (like PBS crashcourse is cool, or philosophize this podcast) and watch debates. You do have to be cautious watching videos, as I have found that some youtubers may mis-represent a person or idea without knowing it. Religious debates can seem dry at first, but when you begin to understand how they are building their philosophical foundation, you may find yourself being drawn in.

People are telling you to wait until college because college text books are reputable sources, and teachers will straighten you out if your take on a philosophy is off.

I second everything David blomstrom said above